# Conversion of Varchar to int

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

Need help! I cannot retrieve data in SQ L, because the value is `100-200`
and it says that it needs to be converted it to Integer, but it is Var char data type.
So i think the problem is about the "-", then the error in the code is in
the data table code, so what to do?

```
Private Sub RetriveData(ByVal ID As String)
    If Sql.HasConnection() = True Then

        Dim DT As DataTable = Sql.ExecuteDataTable("SELECT (EmpID As varchar), FirstName,MidName,LastName,Gender,BirthDate,CivilStat,Address,ContactNum FROM EmployeeTable Where EmpID=" & ID)
        For Each Data As DataRow In DT.Rows
            EmpID_Txt.Text = Data(0)
            FirstName_Txt.Text = Data(1)
            MiddleName_Txt.Text = Data(2)
            LastName_Txt.Text = Data(3)
            Gender_CB.Text = Data(4)
            BirthDate_DTP.Value = Data(5)
            CivilStat_CB.Text = Data(6)
            Address_Txt.Text = Data(7)
            Contact_Txt.Text = Data(8)
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox("System Database Cannot be Connected", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Add the code that you have problem

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to include data in your queries. It can leave you crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: It's not string concatenation per se that leads to injection attacks, it's the concatenation of untrusted data, such as that entered by the user. For example, concatenating a string formed by your program (where you control the values) is perfectly safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the ID as SQL Parameter to your query:

```
"SELECT (EmpID As varchar), FirstName,MidName,LastName,Gender,BirthDate,CivilStat,Address,ContactNum FROM EmployeeTable Where Empid=@empid"
```

Comment: Really? Enclose it in quotes? If it's really a string, that's just one more indication that arbitrary text could be used here, meaning that the quotes technique is practically begging to get hacked. -1 for recommending someone expand or introduce a security flaw into their code. Use  query parameters!

Comment: This will probably solve his actual error message. The security issue is yet another problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually, assuming those `100-200` values are in a table somewhere, I would say the error was in the cranium of the developer who decided to use a `varchar` to store a numeric value :-)

Either that, or the developer who decided to take an otherwise free-form text field and *assume* it was always going to be a single numeric value.

As to how to fix it, one of those paragraphs simply needs to be worked around. If you want a single numeric value in the table, you should change it to a numeric type field, along the way going through all `100-200` style values and cleaning them up (into, for *example,* 150).

If you want to be able to store ranges, then your code that *processes* them is going to have to be more intelligent, such as extracting the lower and upper value from the column and running a loop to process all values within the range, or changing a query from (pseudo-codish query):

```
where EmpId = ?value?
```

into:

```
where EmpId >= ?low? and EmpId <= ?high?
```

We can't really tell you *which* is the best solution based on the information provided, this is likely to be a business decision rather than a technical one.

---

If my assumption is wrong and it's the `ID` argument (being used in the `where` clause) to the function `RetriveData` (sic), then you either need to stop users entering that, or make the code that processes the argument more intelligent (similar to the looping/changed-query suggestion above).

Comment: is there any char from me to use so that i can replace the "-" or if isn't any, made i will just adjust the database